# Colocar Grid Layout en mas de una columna (Solo se coloca en una)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Pues estoy haciendo el buscaminas y al crear lo botones se crean todos en linea recta
Aqui os dejo el codigo con el que creo los botones 
Aun estoy aprendiendo java y Android asi que cualquer critica es bienvenida
El tamaño que entra en la funcion esta bien (puede ser 8-12-16)
Creo que es un error de colocacion del grid

```
public void añadirHijos() {
        g = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.Grid);
        int TAMaux=(TAM*TAM);
        for (int i = 0; i < TAMaux; i++) {
            int iden;
            iden = i;
            ImageButton b;
            b = new ImageButton(this);
            if (i <= TAMaux) {
                System.out.println(TAM+"añadirHIjos");
                b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(g.getLayoutParams().width/TAM,g.getLayoutParams().height/TAM));
                b.setId(iden);
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablero);
                g.addView(b, i);
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
                b.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

y aqui el xml

```
 <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/Grid"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586">
    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vale lo he arreglado con estas dos lineas

```
g.setRowCount(TAM);
g.setColumnCount(TAM);
```

Comment: Dentro del ciclo for? Por fuera? Procura siempre dar contexto a las respuestas, incluso a las que son para tu propia pregunta.

Comment: Fuera del for porque solo hace falta falta una vez aunque no creo que pase nada si lo metes dentro del bucle  porque el tamaño no cambiaria

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el numero de filas (rows) o columnas (columns) no esta especificado en el layout que define el [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout), se puede definir el número de estos elementos mediante las propiedades:

> **[setRowCount(int RowCount)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#setRowCount(int))**
>
> RowCount, se usa solo para generar índices de fila / columna
>   predeterminados cuando no están especificados por los parámetros de
>   diseño de un componente.
>
> **[setColumnCount(int columnCount)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html#setColumnCount(int))**
>
> ColumnCount, se usa solo para generar índices de columna / columna
>   predeterminados cuando no están especificados por los parámetros de
>   diseño de un componente.

--

Ejemplo donde se definen 3 filas y dos columnas para el GridLayout:

```
GridLayout g = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.Grid);
g.setRowCount(3);
g.setColumnCount(2);
```